# flutter: ExpansionTile with controller error in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-sliver, expansion

Hi i am trying to make filter for my search with ExpansionTile in the end of ListView to show more suggestions but i am getting error

```
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 259 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
```

```
A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
```

here is my code:

```
Widget buildListView(){
Map<String, dynamic> searchFilter = {
  "opened": false
}
ExpansionTileController moreSuggestionController = ExpansionTileController();

return ListView(
  children: [
    IconButton(onPressed: (){
      setState((){
        searchFilter["opened"] = !searchFilter["opened"];
      });
    }, 
      icon: Icon(searchFilter["opened"]? Icons.filter_alt: Icons.filter_alt_outlined)
    ),
    if(searchFilter["opened"])
    Container(
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    ExpansionTile(
      controller: moreSuggestionController,
      title: Text("More"),
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          color: Colors.blue,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ]
)
}
```

When i want to open expansion tile everythink works fine, but when i click on IconButton, an error pops...